# PHP - form checkbox submit with ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, forms, submit

I hava set up AJAX script that when you click the button it calls a PHP document.

The problem I have is now some of the variables of the PHP file are set to constant, and now I want them to be conditional to what gets sent when the button is clicked.

I want there to be a check box, that if clicked, will set a PHP variable to be TRUE, while if not click, is set to be FALSE.

I hope the problem is clear enough.

I will now paste the code below because it may help to clarify the problem.

Sorry I have to paste this "huge" chunk of code but I´m not sure which may be useful and which not.

Here is index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadXMLDoc()
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","roulette.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myDiv"><h2>Welcome to Trufa&rsquo;s Roulette</h2></div>
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Spin the Wheel!</button>

</body>
</html>
```

And here is part of roulette.php

```
### Comprare pick to result

//The squares

$sqr_00 = -1;
$sqr_0 = 0;
$sqr_1 = 1;


//Placed bets, if true he placed bet

$bet_straight_placed = array(
 $sqr_00 => false, 
 $sqr_0 => true,
 $sqr_1 => true
);
```

What I would need as I told before, is to replace the FALSE in `$sqr_00 => false`, for a variable that is true when the checkbox is checked!

I hope the question is clear enough to be understood but PLEASE ask for any clarifications needed!

Thanks in advance!

Trufa

EDIT:

Addressing @grossvogel reply I am posting what I understood of his answer becuse it is not working. Sorry and thank you very much!

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadXMLDoc()
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","roulette.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
var isChecked = document.myform.checkbox.checked ? 1 : 0;
xmlhttp.open("GET","roulette.php?boxchecked=" + isChecked,true);
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myDiv"><h2>Welcome to Trufa&rsquo;s Roulette</h2></div>
<form name="myform">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="checkbox" />00<br />
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Spin the Wheel!</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

and the php

```
//The squares

$sqr_00 = -1;
$sqr_0 = 0;
$sqr_1 = 1;


//Placed bets, if true he placed bet
$chb_00 = $_GET['boxchecked'];

$bet_straight_placed = array(
    $sqr_00 => (bool) $chb_00,
    $sqr_0 => true,
    $sqr_1 => true
);

//tell the user what number he piecked

echo "You chose this numbers: " . join(", ", array_keys(array_filter($bet_straight_placed))) . '<br />' . '<br />';
```

I´m sorry I know this must be totally basic but I cant get my head around this AJAX "thing" yet.

Thank you!!!

Comment: One recommendation while you try to get the hang of AJAX: use Firebug. It gives helpful errors, lets you put breakpoints in your javascript, and lets you view the contents of all asynchronous requests. Priceless. http://getfirebug.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your javascript, you can do something like this

```
var isChecked = document.myform.checkbox.checked ? 1 : 0;
xmlhttp.open("GET","roulette.php?boxchecked=" + isChecked,true);
```

Then, in your php, you can read `$_GET['boxchecked']`, which will be 1 if the box was checked, 0 if it wasn't.

**EDIT: Extending the idea to more than one field.**
To do this, you'd add as many checkboxes as you want, say they're names are `value1, value2, value3, ...`. Then you can do something like this:

```
var value1 = document.myform.value1.checked ? 1 : 0;
var value2 = document.myform.value2.checked ? 1 : 0;
var value3 = document.myform.value3.checked ? 1 : 0;
...
```

and

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","roulette.php?value1=" + value1 + "&value2=" + value2 + "&value3=" + value3 ...,true);
```

In php, read `$_GET['value1'], $_GET['value2'], $_GET['value3']...`

Once you get the concepts, you can write some functions to reduce the duplication, if you want.

Comment: Should I put: <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="checkbox" />00<br /> in the index.html   ?

Comment: Yes, you will need to add a checkbox input. it should reside in a form (in my example, `name="myform"`) and its name should match the javascript (in my example, `checkbox`). The value doesn't matter, but you can add `checked="checked"` if you want it to start out checked when the page loads.

Comment: Could you please look at my edit, Im sure this must be absolut basic but I cant yet get it!! Thanks and sorry :)

Comment: The `form` should be named `myform` and the `checkbox` should be named `checkbox`. And for consistent typing, you might want to cast to boolean in your php: `$sqr_00 => (bool) $chb_00`.

Comment: @grossvogel still no working could it be somthing to do with the array_filter($bet_straight_placed)?? I posted what I hace done to my code in a new edit, thanks a lot and sorry agin!!

Comment: @Trufa, i can't quite tell without more info. do this near the top of the php: `print_r($_GET)`. and before the `xmlhttp.open` in the javascript: `alert ("roulette.php?boxchecked=" + isChecked)`

Comment: I will try this out!! Thanks!! in the meantime if you feel like it the source is in: http://viralizate.com/sharefiles/roulette.zip

Comment: @Trufa: I just read your update again and found the problem. I intended for the code I posted to REPLACE your `xmlhttp.open` call instead of coming after the whole function call. You just want to modify the call you were making to add that query string parameter, see?

Comment: @grossvogel of course!!!! Now I see!! I think it is working like a charm!! Thanks so much!! will confirm in 10 min or so but i appreciate the effort!!

Comment: @grossvogel how does this apply to to more that one checkbox? I will give it a try myself anyway. Thanks!!

Comment: Ok I think I have everything I need!! The code is almost working and anything else would be more useful to put is as another question, sot thank you very much and I appreciate the patience!!! cheers